# Django: Difficulties by uploading an image

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-forms

```
return '<%s: %s>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self)
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type int)
```

This is what I get by sending this API request to the server:

[image]

I've added this code because without it raises errors as these:

```
File "/home/dziugas/winteka/winteka/main/serializers.py", line 31, in create
    type=validated_data['type'],
KeyError: 'type'
```

I fixed it with this:

```
if validated_data['user']:
    user = Users.objects.all().filter(pk=validated_data['user'])
    if not user:
        return JsonResponse({'error': 'user was not found'}, status=404)
```

But as I said, I get errors when trying to create a new object.
This is my serializer:

```
class ReportSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    
    class Meta:
        model = Reports
        fields = ('status', 'type', 'user', 'attached_message', 'attached_photo', 'date_created')

    def create(self, validated_data):

        if validated_data['user']:
            user = Users.objects.all().filter(pk=validated_data['user'])
            if not user:
                return JsonResponse({'error': 'user was not found'}, status=404)

        report = Reports(
            status=validated_data['status'],
            type=validated_data['type'],
            user=user,
            attached_message=validated_data['attached_message'] or None,
            attached_photo=validated_data['attached_photo'],
            date_created=validated_data['date_created'],
        )
```

And this is my model:

```
class Reports(models.Model):
    # Report fundamental stuff
    public_id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, editable=False, unique=True, blank=False, null=False, max_length=36)
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=StatusTypes, blank=False, null=False, default=0)
    type = models.IntegerField(choices=ReportTypes, blank=False, null=False, default=10)

    # User Module
    user = models.ForeignKey(Users, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='+', null=False)
    
    # Post Required Stuff
    reports = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False, default=0)
    upvotes = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False, default=0)
    downvotes = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False, default=0)
    comments = models.ManyToManyField('main.ReportMessages', related_name='+')

    attached_message = models.CharField(max_length=300, null=True, blank=True)
    attached_photo = models.ImageField(null=False, blank=False, default='none.png')
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.id
```

Comment: That `if validated_data['user']:` bit shouldn't be necessary at all since DRF knows how to deal with foreignkeys. In fact, the `create` method in its entirety isn't really necessary, since the defaults should work.

Answer (score -1):

you have type error, get int instead of string
change `__str__` to

```
def __str__(self):
  return str(self.id)
```

or change
`return '<%s: %d>' % (self.__class__.__name__, self.id)`

Comment: `File "/home/dziugas/.local/share/virtualenvs/winteka-rp-_dylZ/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/__init__.py", line 1778, in get_prep_value
    ) from e
TypeError: Field 'id' expected a number but got <Users: 5>.`

Comment: what did you change? `return ...` or `__str__`?